# Terraform - AWS Security Group always gets triggered to create an outgoing rule when it already has been created

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this Terraform block which always gets triggered to create the outgoing Security Group rulewhen I run **terraform apply**. Note that this has already been created the first time I ran it:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "outgoing" {
  type        = "egress"
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 0
  protocol    = "all"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg.id
}
```

Here is the output from terraform plan:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

# module.module_name.aws_security_group_rule.outgoing will be created
+ resource "aws_security_group_rule" "outgoing" {
  + cidr_blocks              = [
      + "0.0.0.0/0",
    ]
  + from_port                = 0
  + id                       = (known after apply)
  + ipv6_cidr_blocks         = [
      + "::/0",
    ]
  + protocol                 = "-1"
  + security_group_id        = "sg-123456789"
  + security_group_rule_id   = (known after apply)
  + self                     = false
  + source_security_group_id = (known after apply)
  + to_port                  = 0
  + type                     = "egress"
}
```

What is going on?

Thanks

**EDIT: Why the downvotes? It's a legit question**

Comment: What is the plan output?

Comment: What's your backend config looks like? Have you applied it once successfully?

Comment: The plan shows that the rule is going to be created, because it does not exist. There are no changes here to existing rule at all.

Comment: That is exactly the issue. It's triggering this every time I run terraform plan/apply. The outgoing rule already has been created

Comment: @ChenA. - this has been applied the first time I ran it - yes. And I use S3 as my backend

Comment: @Sean what is the AWS provider version?

Comment: @MarkoE - Version 4.60.0

Comment: Can you update to a newer version, say 4.67.0, and check if you still observe the same behaviour?

Comment: @MarkoE - Just gave it a go. Exactly the same output for "terraform plan"

Comment: Do you also have rules defined in the `aws_security_group` resource?

Comment: @MarkB - no I don't. Just a SG with some tags

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your tfstate if the outgoing rule exists and share it here if possible. Also, share your provider block so we can see the backend.